# Take input from CloudFormation parameter and pass it to script being downloaded from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

While creating along my AWS CloudFormation template I hit the 16KB limitation of user data.... and then I found out I can put the script in S3 (with all my user data) and copy that file over as part of user data and run that script... but my question is how can I take the parameters that I am passing into CloudFormation like below and pass that into the file/script/userdata that I download from S3 that I will run? So how can I pass the parameters from CloudFormation into `/root/usr.sh` script?

Here is my user data:

```
"UserData": {
          "Fn::Base64": {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                "#!/bin/bash -x\n\n",
                "yum -y install tcsh lvm2 sysstat\n\n\n",
                "# AWS CLI download and Installation\n",
                "curl \"https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip\" -o \"/usr/awscli-bundle.zip\"\n",
                "unzip /usr/awscli-bundle.zip -d /usr/awscmdline/\n",
                "/usr/awscmdline/awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws\n",
                "/usr/local/aws/bin/aws configure set region ",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                },
                "\n",
                "/usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp s3://test123/usr.sh /root/usr.sh \n",
                "chmod 744 /root/usr.sh \n",
                "/root/usr.sh"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
```

and here are the sample parameters:

```
"Parameters": {
    "SelectInstanceType": {
      "Description": "EC2 instance type",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "r3.8xlarge",
      "AllowedValues": [
        "r3.large",
        "r3.xlarge",
        "r3.2xlarge",
        "r3.4xlarge",
        "r3.8xlarge",
        "c4.large",
        "c4.xlarge",
        "c4.2xlarge",
        "c4.4xlarge",
        "c4.8xlarge"
      ],
      "ConstraintDescription": "Must be a valid EC2 instance type."
    },
    "Keyname": {
      "Description": "Keypair to use to launch the instance",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
    },
    "IPAddress": {
      "Description": "Private IP",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "10.10.10.X"
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a few ways you could do it...

**Configurations in a file**

You could create a file with your configurations and then read the file from your script. For an example see: [Setting environment variables with user-data](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=139744)

**Set environment variables**

As part of your User Data script, before you download and call a script, set environment variables (also in the above example file).

**Pass parameters when executing your script**

When downloading a script from Amazon S3 and the calling it, append parameters in the same way that your script is currently inserting `AWS::Region`. Your script will then need to read those parameters from the command-line.

Refer to parameters like this: `{ "Ref" : "InstanceTypeParameter" }`

See: [CloudFormation Parameters documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html)

Comment: the 3rd option, seems pretty good but i am not sure if i can pass parameters like { "Ref" : "InstanceTypeParameter" } to bash script ??...can you provide an example if possible ?

Comment: When calling your bash script, append parameters on the command-line exactly like you already do for `aws configure set region`. Your script can then access the parameters as `$1`, `$2`, etc.